# Codeigniter: Validate form field on edit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble and since more than a week trying to find a solution to disallow duplicate form content if it is already exists in database.

So it will check all rows excluding the id (row) what currently I am editing and if same value exists it should give error message.

Here is my Code.

**Position Controller**

```
public function position_edit($id = NULL)
{

    $this->data['title'] = '<i class="fa fa-user"></i> ' . lang('position_edit');

    $this->data['position'] = $this->positions_model->get($id);
    count($this->data['position']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'position could not be found';

    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->db->where('position', $this->input->post('position'));
    !$id || $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
    $pos = $this->positions_model->get();

    echo '<pre>', print_r($pos), '</pre>';

    if (count($pos) > 0) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('position', 'lang:position_code', 'trim|required|max_length[10]|is_unique[positions.position]|xss_clean');            
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', lang('error_position_exists'));
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
        $data = $this->positions_model->array_from_post(array('position', 'label'));
        $this->positions_model->save($data, $id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang('position_record_updated'));
        $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message_type', 'success');
        $this->data['message_type'] = $this->session->flashdata('message_type');

        //redirect('admin/hr/positions', 'refresh');
    }

    // Load the view            
    $this->load->view('hr/positions/edit', $this->data);
}
```

**Position Model**

```
class Positions_Model extends MY_Model
{

    protected $_table_name      =   'positions';
    protected $_order_by        =   'label ASC';

    // This $rules currently not in use since it has been
    // set directly to the controller edit method code
    public $rules               =   array(        
        'position' => array(
                'field' => 'position',
                'label' => 'Position Code',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[10]|xss_clean'
            ),
        'label' => array(
                'field' => 'label',
                'label' => 'Position Label',
                'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean'
            ),                                               

        );


    public function get_new()
    {
        $position = new stdClass();
        $position->position = '';
        $position->label = '';
        return $position;
    }


    public function get_positions($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->get($this->_table_name);        
        return parent::get($id, $single);
    }


    public function get_positions_array($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
    {

        $this->db->get($this->_table_name);        
        $positions = parent::get($id, $single);

        $array = array();
        foreach($positions as $pos){
            $array[] = get_object_vars($pos);
        }

        return $array;
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        // Delete a position
        parent::delete($id);

    }        

}
```

**DB Model**

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model 
{

    protected $_table_name      =   '';
    protected $_primary_key     =   'id';
    protected $_primary_filter  =   'intval';
    protected $_order_by        =   '';
    public    $rules            =   array();
    protected $_timestamps      =   FALSE;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function array_from_post($fields)
    {
        $data = array();

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
        }
        return $data;
    }


    public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE)
    {
        if($id != NULL) {
            $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
            $id = $filter($id);
            $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
            $method = 'row';
        } elseif($single == TRUE) {
            $method = 'row';
        } else {
            $method = 'result';
        }

        if(!count($this->db->ar_orderby)) {
            $this->db->Order_by($this->_order_by);
        }

        return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
    }


    public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->where($where);
        return $this->get(NULL, $single);
    }


    public function save($data, $id = NULL)
    {
        // Set timestamps
        if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
            $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $id || $data['created'] = $now;
            $data['modified'] = $now;
        }

        // Insert
        if ($id === NULL) {
            !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();            
        } else {
        // Update
            $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
            $id = $filter($id);
            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
            $this->db->update($this->_table_name);    
        }

        return $id;                

    }


    public function delete($id)
    {
        $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
        $id = $filter($id);

        if (!$id) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $this->db->delete($this->_table_name);
    }


}
```

I have tried callback function also but it is not working at all and couldn't find what causing the issue.

---

**EDIT:**
***Please note it*** The above code is giving message if I am inserting the value which already exists but it is not validating and storing the data if the row is not exists

---

**Updated**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {

    //print_r($this->positions_model->unique_value('position', $this->uri->segment(4)));

    if($this->positions_model->unique_value('position', $this->uri->segment(4))) {                
        $this->form_validation->set_message('unique_value', lang('error_position_exists'));
    } else {

        $data = $this->positions_model->array_from_post(array('position', 'label'));
        $this->positions_model->save($data, $id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang('position_record_updated'));
        $this->data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message_type', 'success');
        $this->data['message_type'] = $this->session->flashdata('message_type');

        redirect('admin/hr/positions', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function unique_value($field, $id)
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->db->where($field, $this->input->post($field));
    !$id || $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
    $position = $this->positions_model->get();

    if (count($position)) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Note: I don't know what exactly happens to your code, but I wouldn't check between insert or update into the model, just in the controller

I would solve it using a checkExist Model function, that would check if all the values you want to check exists into the DDBB, and work according to it. I would also do it in the controller instead of the model. First, you validate the fields, and then you check if values exists excluding the edit id:

```
$values_from_post = $this->positions_model->array_from_post(array('position', 'label'));

// $editId is to avoid the id of the row you were editing
if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE ) {

    if ( !$this->positions_model->check_duplicate( $values_from_post, $editId ) ) ){
        // Insert Value
    } else {
        // Update Value
    }
```

And in your model, you check the duplicate via a where if the values exists:

```
public function check_duplicate( $values_from_post, $editId ) {

    foreach ( $values_from_post as $key => $value ) {
        $this->db->where( $key, $value );
    }
    $this->db->where('id !=', $editId );

    $result = $this->db->get($this->_table_name);  

    return ( ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) ? true : false );
}
```

Please, I didn't check the code, but that is the idea, instead of doing it in the model, control it in the controller and then insert or update depending of what happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. let me try this. Just to cross confirm `check_duplicate` will goes to my database model or position model?

Comment: Depending on what do you prefer, but I would put into database_mode, so I'd have it available for all the models that extends MY_Model.

Comment: Its not working and validating the duplicate data and storing to the db. I have tried your approach using my code to get row count and it is working but issue is that I have to define any validation rule there.

Comment: please see my last updated two codes. This is working fine but only problem with this is not displaying error message.

Comment: Are you sending it correctly to the view? do you redirect or show the view after failure?

Comment: Yes I am sending it correctly. I think I found another way to do this. Just swapping two different rules based on the post value. It is tricky and messy I know but something is wrong either with my code or some rule which doesn't allow me to use `callback_` or even what you have provided. But still your answer help me to find another way so it worth for me :)

Comment: Hope you'll find the light! ;D.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the default `validation rule` of CodeIgniter for checking the duplicate entries in two columns.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('form_field_name','Title here','required|max_length[255]|unique[table.table_column1,table.table_column2]');
```